# INSERT IGNORE together with ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE - Lock Issue

Tags: java, mysql, sql, jdbc

We inadvertently, had a single query (in a transaction) that had both a INSERT IGNORE and ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE clauses. Now that we think about it, it doesn't make sense. First clause tell the engine to throw away the row, second clause tell the engine to update the row.

Our issue being is that we seem to believe that this type of query causes a JDBC lock issue, notably: "Lock wait timeout exceeded; try restarting transaction". When we took out INSERT IGNORE, this issue seemed to go away all together (after failing 4 times in a row with both).

Could you believe this could cause the lock issue? What does the engine decide to pick when both clauses are present?

We have the latest Java 7 and J-Connector for MySQL.

```
INSERT IGNORE INTO comp.table 
    (`id`,`type`) 
VALUES 
    (1,2) 
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE 
    id=1,type=2;
```

Comment: It never occurred to me to try using `IGNORE` and `ON DUPLICATE KEY` in the same statement; I'm a little surprised that MySQL doesn't throw an error with a statement like that. But it does appear to be valid syntax, according to the Reference Manual. I think the `IGNORE` suppresses the duplicate key error, so the ON DUPLICATE KEY action would never be called.

Comment: @spencer7593 The `IGNORE` doesn't just suppress the duplicate key error, it suppresses other errors as well such as putting a `NULL` in a `NOT NULL` column. I'm fairly sure combining them will result in the same as `INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY` but with the extra error suppression.

Comment: That then should cause a problem in the mysql console; a bug in mysql so to say. One could mentally imagine some if-IGNORE-return not closing some if-ON-DUPLICATE-lock.